# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI.... in DispatcherServlet with name

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I checked out nearly every relevant article on stackoverflow already, but I just cant fix my problem.

Here is the code:
web.xml:

```
   <display-name>Spring3MVC</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name> 
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value> 
    </context-param> 
    <listener> 
        <listener-class> org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener </listener-class> 
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

spring-servlet.xml:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.elso" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>   

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
```

myController:

```
public class myController {
    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public ModelAndView helloWorld() {

        String message = "Hello World, Spring 3.0!";
        return new ModelAndView("hello", "message", message); 
    }
}
```

Web Pages/index.jsp:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Spring 3.0 MVC Series</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="hello.html">Say Hello</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Web Pages/WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Spring 3.0 MVC Series: Hello World - ViralPatel.net</title>
</head>
<body>
    ${message}
</body>
</html>
```

So when i launch the appication the index.jsp is loaded correctly but when i click on the href to navigate to hello.jsp i got a 404 error and the server log says:

```
No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/Elso/hello.html] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'
```

I've checked out dozens of articles like that, but I just can't find the mistake, anybody has any idea what could it be?

Comment: Maybe you should change hello.html to hello.jsp?

Comment: Does it work if you change the request mapping to `@RequestMapping("/hello.html")` ?

Comment: Hi! Tried both of them already , none of them works :/

Comment: You don't show all your Spring config - you may be missing `<mvc:annotation-driven />` so annotations like @RequestMapping will work...

Comment: I added <mvc:annotation-driven /> row to the spring-servlet.xml but still not working

Comment: Is your controller annotated with @Controller?

Comment: It's working now thanks! Stupid mistake i did

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You could try and add an `@Controller` annotation on top of your myController Class and
try the following url `/<webappname>/my/hello.html`.
This is because `org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping` prepends **/my** to each RequestMapping in the myController class.

Answer (score 71):

Add

```
  <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
```

to spring-servlet.xml

Comment: Thanks a lot. This solved my issue. Now it takes my welcome file by default.

Comment: I got `The prefix "mvc" for element "mvc:default-servlet-handler" is not bound.` after adding this. Any idea?

Comment: xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"

Comment: Add ```http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd``` to schema

Answer (score 32):

If you are using

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

make sure your spring-servlet.xml has correct

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.....controller" /> tag.
```

Basically, you need to include all the packages where you have used the annotation in your java code.

Also, please ensure you do not have duplication of *component-scan* (for a discovery of beans). If your config XML already contains the element, then any of your Controller classes that are annotated with *@ComponentScan(basePackages=*... needs to be stripped of the said annotation.

Comment: I added this. But I get the error 'The prefix "mvc" for element "mvc:annotation-driven" is not bound.'

Comment: This was it for me - we inherited the project and the parameter for the package names had not been updated to the new codebase.

Answer (score 15):

I solved my issue with : 
Java Build Path -> JRE system library - > Edit -> Alternate  JRE ->  -> Finish

As it was configured to JDK folder so it was giving Exception

Comment: this worked for me, thanks a ton!

Comment: BOOM! Thanks for the tip

Comment: It is worked for me, can anyone please tell me how does it solves the problem.

Comment: worked for me too.

Answer (score 13):

Make sure

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.hireartists.web.controllers"/>
```

points to proper package that contains controllers.

Comment: Spring should stress this in their documentation. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 10):

Please check your `[PROJECT_NAME]\target\classes` directory to see whether `myController.class` is generated or not.

If not, please check all your java source code whether there are any compilation errors.

Answer (score 9):

Try:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Worked for me!

Answer (score 9):

If you are using Java code based on Spring MVC configuration then enable the `DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer` in the `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` object.

```
@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) { 
        configurer.enable();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Check ur Bean xmlns..

I also had similar problem, but I resolved it by adding mvc xmlns.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd">


    <context:component-scan base-package="net.viralpatel.spring3.controller" />
    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 3):

addition of `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` worked for me.
Add it before line `<context:component-scan ............/>`

Comment: where did you add it? please elaborate it a bit

Comment: There is no point in adding a solution without elaborating. Where did you place this?

Comment: I have added <mvc:annoation-driven/> just before line  "<context:component-scan .........../>" in dispatcher-servlet.xml

Answer (score 3):

If you want to serve .html files, you must add this `<mvc:default-servlet-handler />` in your spring config file. .html files are static.
Hope that this can help someone.

Answer (score 3):

It is not finding the controllers, this is basic issues.
it can be due to following reasons.

A. inside WEB-INF folder you have file web.xml that refers to dispatcherServlet. Here it this case is mvc-config.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

B. This mvc-config.xml file have namespaces and it has to scan the controllers.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.vimal.spring.controllers" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

C.  Check for the correctness of the package name where you have the controllers. It should work.

```
All Controllers must be Annotated with @Controller.
```

Answer (score 2):

Had the exact same error and it took me a long time trying to understand it. It is most likely down to compilation errors, the java classes did not get published in your servlet. Please check this by going in the server that you are using \tmp1\wtpwebapps[PROJECT_NAME]\WEB-INF\classes\ and try to find you controller classes to see whether or not they have been published. If not you need to get to the bottom of any compilation errors.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using maven as build tool for project , build your project properly,your changes in the code and xml files are not reflecting after compilations.

Answer (score 2):

If you depend on [Spring Social](http://projects.spring.io/spring-social/), check that you have configured a Web Controller bean:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.social.connect.web.ConnectController;
import org.springframework.social.connect.ConnectionFactoryLocator;
import org.springframework.social.connect.ConnectionRepository;

...

@Bean
public ConnectController connectController(ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator, ConnectionRepository connectionRepository) {
    return new ConnectController(connectionFactoryLocator, connectionRepository);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if you are using maven then do run maven install command before you run your web app on a server as it will generate a class file for your controller and in my experience that is what your application has been missing.

Comment: Add more details and references

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and after lots of reserach I found the classes were not getting published in my target folder. So I had run the below two commands from cmd

1. mvn clean install
2. mvn package

Surprisingly I was able to access the page and error was gone. Same can be verified from target folder where you will be able to find the complied classes which were missing earlier.

Comment: Works for me also..

Answer (score 2):

Add `@Controller` to your controller or where ever you have the `@RequestMapping` for you json end point.

This worked for me while deploying a similar application.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Maven ,
Add these to your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
<groupid>javax.servlet</groupid>
<artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
<version>1.2</version>
<scope>runtime</scope>
```

```
<dependency>
<groupid>taglibs</groupid>
<artifactId>standard</artifactId>
<version>1.1.2</version>
<scope>runtime</scope>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, and thanks for your answer. This question has been flagged for review because of its brevity. It would help if you could expand the question to include an explanation of the problem the OP is having and why your solution helps.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue, but after putting the namespace below, it works fine:

```
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
```

Answer (score 1):

Removing the Tomcat Server and adding new tomcat configuration in Eclipse resolved issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

In pom.xml make sure packaging is set to `war` like `<packaging>war</packaging>` ,not to jar or any thing else.

Answer (score 0):

What is /Elso?

You try:

```
@RequestMapping("/Elso")
public class myController {

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public ModelAndView helloWorld() {

        String message = "Hello World, Spring 3.0!";
        return new ModelAndView("hello", "message", message); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! I tried it, still not working, Elso is the name of the Project.

Comment: i think you are missing the annotation @Controller at your controller class