# Error saying : No mapping found for HTTP request with URI in DispatcherServlet due to Maven dependency

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to authenticate and authorize using role base in spring using hibernate in java configuration. When I run the server then it gives me error sarying no mapping found for the URI in servlet.

```
public class ShoppingInitializerWeb implements WebApplicationInitializer {

public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    ctx.register(ShoppingServletConfig.class);
    ctx.setServletContext(container);
    ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));

    servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    servlet.addMapping("/*");

}
}
```

ShoppingServletConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.project.shopping")
public class ShoppingServletConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{
 @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/ui/view/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

        return viewResolver;
    }
```

WebConfigStatic.java

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration

@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.project.shopping")
public class WebConfigStatic extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**").addResourceLocations("/ui/js/");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("/ui/css/");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/*.html/**").addResourceLocations("/ui/view/");
}
}
```

This is my controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class UserController {
@RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/home" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String homePage(ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("user", getPrincipal());
    return "welcome";
}
```

And I have got welcome.jsp in webapp/WEB-INF/ui/view

Here is the error in console:

```
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/Shoping/home] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
```

I looked up all the related errors and tried solving but couldn't get it solved.

Comment: try with @RequestMapping("/") to @RequestMapping("/Shopping")

Comment: @Amit done but the same error

Comment: did you try with servlet.addMapping("/"); ?

Comment: I am talking about addMapping..

Comment: yes sorry I wrote @RequestMapping there in the comment but I wanted to write .addMapping 
Yes I changed it also

Comment: I am not sure but you should add @EnableWebMvc annotation above the ShoppingServletConfig.java file.

Comment: Done as you said but the same error again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171524/discussion-between-amit-and-bishwa-karki).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No mapping found for HTTP request with URI.... in DispatcherServlet with name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18683847/no-mapping-found-for-http-request-with-uri-in-dispatcherservlet-with-name)

Comment: Are you sure about your package names, @ComponentScan ? (shoping / shopping and others)

Comment: Yes that is all correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have faced a same project in my Spring project and I tried every possible way but no solution didn't work for that project however, finally I got a solution.

After **adding maven dependencies into project deployment assembly**, my project worked perfectly. So, you can try with below procedures, it should work if your code is perfect.

> Right click on Project then select **Properties** > **Deployment Assembly** >
>   then click **add** button > **Java Build path entries** > Select **Maven
>    dependencies** > click **Finish** button.

then update maven project, and then mvn clean install ... then run.

I hope, it would work.

Comment: Thank you it solved the problem but again it is saying in log     ' Disabling contextual LOB creation as JDBC driver reported JDBC version [3] less than 4'