# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/favicon.ico] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'

Tags: spring-mvc

Im getting an error "No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/favicon.ico] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'"
while running this spring mvc hello world application using jetty.

Im Providing my web.xml and servlet.xml , im running it using Jetty server ,

Web.xml

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Spring Web MVC Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

**mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mkyong.common.controller" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

My controller

```
package com.mkyong.common.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/welcome")
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printWelcome(ModelMap model) {

        model.addAttribute("message", "Spring 3 MVC Hello World");
        return "hello";

    }

}
```

can someone help me on this .

Comment: do you have a `favicon.ico` ?

Comment: no i dont think i have a favicon.ico

Answer (score 2):

Put this in your configuration file

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/favicon.ico" location="/favicon.ico" />
```

here location is the path of favicon.ico file. so please give a correct path.

Comment: Thank you sandeep , i have added that and tried to launch the application through http://localhost:8080/ , but now im getting the following error    "No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'"

Comment: <mvc:default-servlet-handler/> add this

Comment: I have added this to my servlet.xml , no errors are found but still the HelloWorld is not getting displayed

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18683847/no-mapping-found-for-http-request-with-uri-in-dispatcherservlet-with-name