# Passing url variable results in "No mapping found for HTTP request"

Tags: java, spring

I am able to write the following method which loads my static files fine:

```
@GetMapping("/register")
public String newRegister(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
    return "register";
}
```

However, when I add and `{Id}` to the url:

```
@GetMapping("/register/{Id}")
public String newRegister(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
    return "register";
}
```

all of the static files error, with a message such as:

```
2018-07-05 08:42:24.969  WARN 52397 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             :     
No mapping found for HTTP request with 
URI [/hi/js/all.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
2018-07-05 08:42:24.969  WARN 52397 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound          
 : No mapping found for HTTP request with 
URI [/hi/img/google-logo.svg] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
 2018-07-05 08:42:25 DEBUG GreetingController:40 - *****123
 2018-07-05 08:42:25.563  WARN 52397 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping found for HTTP request with 
URI [/hi/css/all.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
```

Why does this occur, and how would I fix it? Here is an example of the project structure:

[image]

Comment: can you add your project structure image? do not know if it's under `WEB-INF`

Comment: @lucumt sure, please see updated question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18683847/no-mapping-found-for-http-request-with-uri-in-dispatcherservlet-with-name/23141922

Comment: @JohnJoe ok -- but my static resources **do** load. They just fail to load when I add a variable to the url.

Comment: why you calling `all.js` ?

Comment: @JohnJoe those are static files in the html template that are referenced.

Comment: so your `{Id}` actually hold `js/all.js` ? Just a wild guess, maybe the url is incorrect.

Comment: It might happen due to clash between `register/{Id}` and `register/js/all.js`.
You could try to set up separate way of serving static resources: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-static-resources

Comment: @Ivan it's all static resources and not just the `js` file. Please see updated stacktrace.

Comment: can you please clean and build your project ?

Comment: Could you please also provide the setup of the `viewResolver`?

Comment: If you using pom, try `mvn clean spring-boot:run`

Comment: @JohnJoe it seems like this may have been a collision with the thymeleaf namespace. I'll post an answer once I know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Given you have added a path variable to the request - `GetMapping("/register/{Id}")`, The method needs @PathVariable parameter. So this will be something like

```
@GetMapping("/register/{Id}")
public String newRegister(HttpServletRequest request, Model model, @PathVariable("Id") long id) {
 return "register";
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: still get the same error (don't worry I didn't downvote you).

Comment: Lol.. Is it possible to include the request url?

Comment: You definitely are not forced to add a `@PathVariable` annotated parameter when using a uri variable in the path mapping. This answer is wrong.